# ISLR book Lab 3.6.2 assigns model to lm.fit... why?

Tags: r

(being a SWE trying to get introduced to stats via R, this particular question is bothering me)

In the first linear regression lab of the [ISLR book](http://faculty.marshall.usc.edu/gareth-james/ISL/) the example regression assigns lm.fit as:

```
> lm.fit=lm(col1~col2)
```

But inspecting lm.fit with `> ?lm.fit` and `> lm.fit` before this assignment it's apparent that `lm.fit` is a low level function used by `lm` to compute a model. And from `?lm.fit`: *"`lm` calls the lower level functions `lm.fit`, etc"*...

After the assignment it is assigned the value of the model:

```
> lm.fit
Call:
lm(formula = medv ~ lstat, data = Boston)
...
```

What's happening here? Why is the lab replacing the `lm.fit` function with resultant model? What happens now when `lm` tries to *"call the lower level lm.fit"* function?

Comment: It's just a confusing choice of name by the authors of the book.  It'll still work. In production code, you keep object names in environments to avoid this situation.

Comment: Yeah... That is pretty poor naming. That said: "*There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things.*" we bumped onto the second one here. (Quote by P. Karlton)

Comment: When you encounter a statement like **lm.fit=lm(col1~col2)** in R, you can think of it this way.  On the right hand side of the statement, you are using the **lm()** function to regress col1 (dependent variable) on col2 (independent variable) via simple linear regression.  On the left hand side of the command, you are saving the model fit under the name **lm.fit** so that you can query it later in order to obtain a model summary, model coefficients, confidence intervals, predictions, diagnostic plots, etc.

Comment: For example, **summary(lm.fit)** gives a summary of the model fit, **coef(lm.fit)** gives the estimated intercept and slope, **confint(lm.fit)** gives 95% confidence intervals for the true intercept and slope, and **plot(lm.fit)** creates and display graphical model diagnostics.

Comment: The problem you encountered is that the name assigned to the model fit, **lm.fit**, also happens to be the name of the low level function **lm.fit()**, which you discovered is used as a workhorse by the **lm()** function during the model fitting process.  The model fit object **lm.fit** and the workhorse function **lm()** are 2 distinct objects as far as R is concerned.  R is smart enough to distinguish between the two entities even if you, as a user, may be confused by them.  Even if you name your model fit **lm.fit**, you are NOT going to override the **lm.fit()** function.

Comment: If you want to avoid confusion, just use a different name for the fitted model. For example, **model.1 = lm(col1~col2)**.  Then you can use all of the usual commands with this new name: **summary(model.1)**, **coef(model.1)**, **confint(model.1)**, **plot(model.1)**, etc.